# How to implode comma separated outside string

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

I have Array

```
( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

I want to make it:

```
'1','2','3'
```

How to do that I was tried using implode but the result is:

```
'1,2,3'
```

Can anyone help me, please ? Thanks.

Comment: What is the data structure of your desired result? Is it a string or an array?

Comment: result is array

Comment: Is this an XY Problem where you are going to feed that string to an SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the single quotes into your [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) glue string, and at the outsides of the result string:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
echo "'" . implode("','", $array) . "'";
```

Output:

```
'1','2','3'
```

This will work regardless of whether your array values are strings or numbers e.g.

```
$array = ['1', '2', '3'];
echo "'" . implode("','", $array) . "'";
```

Output:

```
'1','2','3'
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/83jLF)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3');
$comma_separated = "'" . implode ( "', '", $array ) . "'";
echo $comma_separated;
```

Comment: Have you checked the output of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

If the result is an array (like you stated in your comments) then you can use `array_map` to convert your array of integers to an array of strings:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
var_dump(array_map('strval', $arr));
```

This will result in an array of strings:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: From the output of a `print_r` you can't really tell that the input is not already an array of strings (the output of your code looks exactly like OPs input array). The fact that OP is using `implode` suggests the output is supposed to be a string. The comment doesn't make a lot of sense in that context though. Who knows!

Comment: @Nick yeah, I suppose its just another option, I've changed `print_r` to `var_dump` now though. The OP isn't being very clear :P

Answer (score 0):

[sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) will work in this case:

```
$arr = ['1', '2', '3'];
$str = implode(', ', array_map(function($val){return sprintf("'%s'", $val);}, $arr));
echo $str; //'1', '2', '3'
```